# Table of Contents and \hyperref pointing to different positions of newtcbtheorem environment

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, tcolorbox

I have a user-defined variant of the `newtcbtheorem` environment below, and you can see that within it I have an `addcontentsline` to add the Theorem number and title to the ToC. I have included a `\phantomsection` so that the referral from the ToC points above the title and not below it (as was happening).

However, even though that works, when using `\hyperref` in my document to link to the same theorem, it points below the title of the theorem, i.e

[image]

How can I get it to mimic the pointer of the ToC link to the theorem?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath , amsthm , amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{fullpage}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue!80!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\betternewtcbtheorem}{O{}mmmm}
{
    \newtcbtheorem[#1]{#2inner}{#3}{#4}{#5}
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{#2}{O{}}
    {
        \keys_set:nn { hushus/tcb } { ##1 }
        %Add to ToC
        \phantomsection
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#3\hspace{0.2em} \thechapter.{ \the\numexpr\value{thmcounter}+1\relax}  {
                \if\l__hushus_tcb_title_tl\empty
                \else   
                :\hspace{0.4em} \l__hushus_tcb_title_tl
                \fi} }
        %Finish adding to ToC
        \hushus_tcb_begin:nVV {#2inner} \l__hushus_tcb_title_tl \l__hushus_tcb_label_tl
    }
    {
    \end{#2inner}
}
\cs_if_exist:cF { c@#5} { \newcounter{#5} }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hushus_tcb_begin:nnn
{
\begin{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hushus_tcb_begin:nnn { nVV }
\keys_define:nn { hushus/tcb }
{
    title .tl_set:N = \l__hushus_tcb_title_tl,
    label .tl_set:N = \l__hushus_tcb_label_tl,
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{thmcounter}[chapter]
\betternewtcbtheorem[number within = chapter,use counter=thmcounter]{thm}{Theorem}%
{
    enhanced,
    colback=green!10,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    top=3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift = 5mm, yshift=-1.5mm},
    boxed title style = {colback=green!35!black}
}{thm}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \begin{thm}[title = The Amazing Theorem, label= 1.1]
        This is the most amazing theorem
    \end{thm}
    Here I link to the theorem \hyperref[thm:1.1]{Corollary 1.1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The \ref commands points to a destination set by tcolorbox, not to your \phantomsection.

tcolorbox uses `\Hy@raisedlink` to raise the link, so you can adjust the location of the destination by changing locally the default length used to raise the link. The default value is `\baselineskip` and I leave it to you to check if you need to reset it later somewhere ...

```
\def\HyperRaiseLinkDefault{1cm}%
```

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath , amsthm , amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue!80!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\betternewtcbtheorem}{O{}mmmm}
{
    \newtcbtheorem[#1]{#2inner}{#3}{#4}{#5}
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{#2}{O{}}
    {   
        \keys_set:nn { hushus/tcb } { ##1 }
        %Add to ToC
        \phantomsection
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#3\hspace{0.2em} \thechapter.{ \the\numexpr\value{thmcounter}+1\relax}  {
                \if\l__hushus_tcb_title_tl\empty
                \else
                :\hspace{0.4em} \l__hushus_tcb_title_tl
                \fi} }
        %Finish adding to ToC
        \def\HyperRaiseLinkDefault{1cm}%
        \hushus_tcb_begin:nVV {#2inner} \l__hushus_tcb_title_tl \l__hushus_tcb_label_tl
    }
    {
    \end{#2inner}
}
\cs_if_exist:cF { c@#5} { \newcounter{#5} }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hushus_tcb_begin:nnn
{
\begin{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hushus_tcb_begin:nnn { nVV }
\keys_define:nn { hushus/tcb }
{
    title .tl_set:N = \l__hushus_tcb_title_tl,
    label .tl_set:N = \l__hushus_tcb_label_tl,
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{thmcounter}[chapter]
\betternewtcbtheorem[number within = chapter,use counter=thmcounter]{thm}{Theorem}%
{
    enhanced,
    colback=green!10,
    colframe=green!35!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    top=3mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift = 5mm, yshift=-1.5mm},
    boxed title style = {colback=green!35!black}
}{thm}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \begin{thm}[title = The Amazing Theorem, label= 1.1]
        This is the most amazing theorem
    \end{thm}
    Here I link to the theorem \hyperref[thm:1.1]{Corollary 1.1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. If I may ask, if ```\ref``` points to the destination set by tcolorbox, what do the lines in the table of contents look like as code? It can't be ref, because if you try removing the ```\phantomsection``` I have in the environment definition, it doesn't even point to the theorem properly anymore..

Comment: your addtocontents code is very early, so it will point to whatever destination is just before the tcolorbox.